# Run animation every time it's in a viewport

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```js
//new IntersectionObserver();
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    //console.log(entry)
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.firstChild.classList.add('tag');
    } else {
      entry.target.firstChild.classList.remove('tag');
    }
  })
})

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```

```css
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}

section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  /*scroll-margin: 5vh;*/
  min-height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tag {
  color: #0000;
  --g: linear-gradient(beige 0 0) no-repeat;
  background: var(--g), var(--g);
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box, text;
  background-clip: padding-box, text;
  animation: t 1.2s .5s both, b 1.2s 1.3s both;
}

p1 {
  line-height: 25px;
  color: beige;
  overflow-wrap: wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  max-width: 60vw;
  font-size: 1,5vw;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-right: 1vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  text-align: justify;
}

h1 { color: beige; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; 
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px; margin: 0 0 0;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

@keyframes t {
  to {
    background-size: 150% 100%
  }
}

@keyframes b {
  to {
    background-position: -200% 0, 0 0
  }
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}


@keyframes t{
  to {background-size: 150% 100%}

}
@keyframes b {
  to {background-position:-200% 0,0 0}
}

h1 { color: beige; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; 
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 50px; margin: 0 0 0;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>   
    <head>
        <html lang="cz"></html>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styly.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
      
      <!-- 1. okn - Úvod -->
      <section style="display: flex;">
        <img class="logo" src="Original.svg" id="logo"> <!-- logo  -->
        <p3> <!--  -->
          text tmsdlnvlsůsnskf
        </p3>
        
        

        <p2> 
          „text text text text text text text text text text text“
        </p2>
        <div class="sipky_d">
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
         </div>
      </section>

      <!-- 2. window -->
      <section>
        <div class="sipky_n">
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
        </div>

        <img class="profile_photo" src="foto.jpg" id="pfp">
        <p1 style="float: right;">
          text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p1>
        <div class="links">
          <button class="button" onclick="window.open('tel:')">Call</button>
          <button class="button" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:mail'">e-mail</button>
          <button class="button" onclick="window.location.href='www.google.com'">Facebook</button>
       </div>

        <p4>text text text text text text text text text text text</p4>

       <div class="sipky_d">
        <div class="sipka_d"></div>
        <div class="sipka_d"></div>
        <div class="sipka_d"></div>
       </div>
       
      </section>

      <!-- 3. window -->
      <section>
       <div class="sipky_n">
        <div class="sipka_n"></div>
        <div class="sipka_n"></div>
        <div class="sipka_n"></div>
       </div>

        
        <p1>  
          <h1><span class="tag">Text that I want to animate</span></h1>
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text 
        </p1>

          <div class="sipky_d">
            <div class="sipka_d"></div>
            <div class="sipka_d"></div>
            <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          </div>

      </section>
  
      <!-- 4. window -->
      <section>
      <div class="sipky_n">
        <div class="sipka_n"></div>
        <div class="sipka_n"></div>
        <div class="sipka_n"></div>
      </div>


       <p1> 
         <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
         <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
         <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
         </p1>

         <div class="sipky_d">
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
         </div>
      </section>

      <!-- 5. window -->
      <section>
        <div class="sipky_n">
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
        </div>

        <p1>
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>Správní právo
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p1>

        <div class="sipky_d">
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
         </div>
      </section>

      <!-- 6. window -->
      <section>
            <div class="sipky_n">
              <div class="sipka_n"></div>
              <div class="sipka_n"></div>
              <div class="sipka_n"></div>
            </div>
            <p1>
              <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
              <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
              <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
              <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
              <ul>
                <li>text text text text text text text text text text text</li>
                <li>text text text text text text text text text text text</li>
                <li>text text text text text text text text text text text</li>
              </ul>
            </p1>
            <div class="sipky_d">
              <div class="sipka_d"></div>
              <div class="sipka_d"></div>
              <div class="sipka_d"></div>
             </div>
      </section>

      <!-- 7. window -->
      <section>
        <div class="sipky_n">
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
        </div>
        <p1>
          <br><br>Jtext text text text text text text text text text text
        
        <br><br>
        <div class="map-responsive">
            <iframe src="" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        
          text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>
          text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p1>
        <div class="sipky_d">
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
          <div class="sipka_d"></div>
         </div>
      </section>
  
      <!-- 8. window -->
      <section style="scroll-padding: -50vh;">
        <div class="sipky_n">
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
          <div class="sipka_n"></div>
        </div>
        <p1>
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text

          text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text text text text text text text text
        </p1>
        <div style="margin-left: 18vw;"></div> 
      </section>

      <div style="scroll-margin-block-end: -20vh;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I want to run the animation every time it comes into the viewport. In the main html body I have several `<section>` elements and a scroll snap feature. The animation plays right and works, but plays only once. I would like it to play every time it comes into the viewport.

I tried several tutorials in JS that play the animation when it comes into viewport, but none worked.

I added the observer in JavaScript and I have referenced the JavaScript in the HTML. The animation plays once. When I scroll up or down, the animation doesn't play and there is only the text. It looks like the animation plays just once and then never again unless I refresh the page.

Edit2: I added sample of the html. The page consists of several sections that are snapped into view as the user scrolls up or down. The text should animate each time the section comes into view.

Edit3: I used the provided code and placed it both into my respective files as well as into the snippet. In the snippet it works perfectly, but when I run the html file in my browser it still animated just once. There is no other js. Can some other css code make it not work?

Edit4: The entire html code is here and it works as intended. Even when I paste the entire css code into the snippet, it works. I tried to do it over, I copied the html into new file, added the css only for the animated text and the javascript. Once again it played only once. I tried removing the css code in "html" and "section" parts of the css, none of it worked. I'm considering scrapping this feature.

Edit5: I put the js script directly into the html like this:

```html
 <p1>  
          <h1><span class="tag">Text that I want to animate</span></h1>
          <script>
            const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
               entries.forEach((entry) => {
               //console.log(entry)
               if (entry.isIntersecting) {
               entry.target.firstChild.classList.add('tag');
              } else {
               entry.target.firstChild.classList.remove('tag');
               }
              })
             })

         const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
         hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
          </script>
          <br><br>text text text
          <br><br>text text text text
          <br><br>text text text text 
</p1>
```

And it works exactly as intended. So thank you everyone who contributed. Big thanks to **A Haworth** for making fixes to the javascript!

Comment: what do you means by `every time it comes into the viewport` ? a viewport is just about environment concept...

Comment: If you want to run it every time that h1 comes into the viewport, look into Intersection Observer.

Comment: I mean when the text that is animated is visible to the user. When the user will scroll up, it wont be visible. When the user scrolls down, the text will animete.

Comment: That’s what IntersectionObserver will help you with.

Comment: Have you checked the console? Since there are a few errors in your code. 1. The first `new IntersectionObserver();` can be omitted. 2. `foreach` should be `forEach`

Comment: ‘Not working’ isn’t very helpful. What isn’t working? What debugging have you done? Eg is the observer code being entered at all? Perhaps create a runnable snippet to make it easier for us to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What makes your snippet scrollable? Please check that it shows the problem as I can’t make it scroll.

Comment: Now it scrolls, as well as having the code from my answer, it is working fine for me. Is there still a problem?

Comment: I have absolutelly no idea why it doesnt work. I posted all relevant code into the snippet (I left out the ones that style other parts of the web such as map or animation for the arrows) and it works flawlessly. I will try to make the site again from scratch if there is a problem in there or something.

Thank you for the code, that was a big help.

Comment: So the snippet does work for you? If so, yes you need to provide code that doesn't work!

Comment: The snippet works perfectly, but when inserted in the rest of the code it doesnt work. I could try to transfer all of the code into the snippet.

Comment: This may be a case where we have to see the actual site where it is not working since everything on this question as presented works ok. Have you got the usual headings, eg doctype in your real life system?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly like I have it in the "live" files and site. I had the idea to try to put the css/js directly into the html tag and see it that could fix it. I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Okay, I somehow made it work? See edit5 in my post. Thank you everyone for your help! I whish you all a wonderful morning, day or evening.

Comment: Note that html5 in the doctype shd. be html - and I imagine the closing html tag that was there before on line 2 was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the errors pointed out by @Reyno, which should be picked up by looking at the console of your browser's devtools inspect facility, the tag class is being added/remved incorrectly in two ways - a dot before the tag and it is being added to the h1 while you are wanting it to be on its child span.

This snippet does some simple corrections of these errors:

```js
//new IntersectionObserver();
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    //console.log(entry)
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.firstChild.classList.add('tag');
    } else {
      entry.target.firstChild.classList.remove('tag');
    }
  })
})

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```

```css
.tag {
  color: #0000;
  --g: linear-gradient(beige 0 0) no-repeat;
  background: var(--g), var(--g);
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box, text;
  background-clip: padding-box, text;
  animation: t 1.2s .5s both, b 1.2s 1.3s both;
}

@keyframes t {
  to {
    background-size: 150% 100%
  }
}

@keyframes b {
  to {
    background-position: -200% 0, 0 0
  }
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

div {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>My text to animate</span></h1>
<div>big div to create scrolling</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want to achieve. Unfortunatelly, the text animates only once. I added a sample of the html in case there lies the issue. I honestly dont know where is the issue.

Comment: I don't understand the HTML you have just added to the question. What is a p1 element? Please make the code into a runnable snippet  and make sure is shows the problem. (as it stands I can't see that your HTML would cause any potential scrolling).

Comment: I added the snippet. I used your code (that I added into my files) and it works flawlessly. Why it doesnt work in the file is beyond me. I guess some other part of the code interacts with it? There is no js beside that one. Can it be an issue of css?